# Excel : Grouping based on column values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns in excel
eg:

```
Component    Size

A1           12
A2           5
A1           6
A3           10
A2           4
```

I need to get the output as:

```
A1        18   (sum of the values for A1)
A2        9
A3        10
```

Can you please suggest a solution without using macro

Answer (score 5):

Or alternatively, you can use a `pivot table`.

1. Select your data table.
2. Go to `Insert` > `PivotTable`
3. Drag the fields in the 'boxes'; Components in 'Raw Labels' and Size in 'Sum Values'

And you obtain this:

[image]

You can copy the result table to another sheet.

Comment: @ Jerry Thanks for the reply. However, the values in the size column are dynamic. I have to keep summing as and when the size appear on selecting the component (a dropdown) and some other additional parameters .

Comment: @PDM You can use PivotTable for dynamic ranges as well. You could select the whole columns and you will only need to refresh the pivot table (you can see the refresh button in the picture I posted in my answer). If you add additional columns though, you can edit the PivotTable source by clicking on 'Change Data Source' to the right of 'Refresh'. I can't see your actual data to be sure, but I consider PivotTables easier in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this a lot. The easiest way is to copy column A containing your keys (A1, A2, etc in your example) to a separate sheet, let's say your data is Sheet1 and this list is Sheet2.

Remove duplicates from this list and sort as desired.

Then use the `sumif` formula on this second sheet (see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) for advanced documentation).

In your case, the formula in Sheet2!B1 would be:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, A1, Sheet1!B:B)
```